# how to best structure multiple time series for multiple stocks?

Tags: pandas

I'm new to the world of Pandas, and am trying to figure out best practices for structuring the data frame(s) for various time calculations on financial time series.

I'm currently importing pricing time series as follows:

```
data_frames = { }
START_DATE = '2000-01-01'
TICKERS = [ 'SPY', 'VWO', 'TLT']

for ticker in TICKERS:
  data_frames[ticker] = pdr.get_data_tiingo( ticker, start = START_DATE, api_key='xxxxxxxx' )
```

After that import, the first few columns of data_frames['SPY'] look like:

```
                         adjClose     adjHigh      adjLow     adjOpen  adjVolume  \
symbol date                                                                    
SPY    2000-01-03  101.407597  103.368638  100.318130  103.368638    8164300   
       2000-01-04   97.441937  100.448866   97.365652  100.078415    8089800   
       2000-01-05   97.616251   98.683897   95.698789   97.572673   12177900   
       2000-01-06   96.047419   98.662140   96.047419   97.354779    6227200
```

What would be the recommended way to combine the time series for the three tickers if I want to then perform calculations comparing the time series.  My first thought was that I should concatenate the dataframes with

```
dfs_concat = pd.concat( [data_frames['SPY'], data_frames['VWO'], data_frames['TLT']] )
```

and then use the apply function

```
dfs_concat.apply( some_cross_asset_calculation_here, axis = 1 )
```

but inside some_cross_asset_calculation_here( ), I have access to the dataframe row for one ticker, but not for the other tickers.

I suppose I could create columns in one dataframe for each ticker, so that I have columns such as SPY_adjClose, SPY_adjOpen, TLT_adjClose, TLT_adjOpen.  But that doesn't feel quite right.

It feels like I must be missing an obvious approach to how to best handle the data.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: pdr is not defined in your code.  Can you define it?

Comment: @anon01 i'm guessing that's pandas datareader

Comment: Try bringing them all in at once putting the stock symbols in a list. df = pdr.get_data_tiingo( TICKERS, start = START_DATE, api_key='xxxxxxxx' )

Answer (score 0):

You could drop the index level `symbol` into a column as categorical variable

```py
df = data_frames.drop_index(level='symbols')
```

Then you can select your data based on that column (`df[df['type''] == 'SPY']`) or perform operations per group (`df.groupby('type').apply(som_func)` or `for name, group in df.groupby('type): ...').

This should also be possible on the index axis but I prefer to store that in columns